# Thermal Wheatstone Bridge

Tags: thermal-conductivity, thermoelectricity

I am currently studying about the thermal conductivity of rods, as I am reading a Idea popped up in my mind that is ,

Is the  concept of wheat stone bridge Valid to thermal resistors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle of the bridge should work for you.  You would need a heat source and sink of known fixed temperature, and a rod of known thermal conductivity the same size and shape as the one you are testing.  Connect the two rods end to end. Connect one to the heat source and the other to the sink.  Let them come to equilibrium and measure the temperature at the junction.  The ratio of the temperature drops should be inversely proportional to the ratio of the conductivities.

Comment: i think it would not work bcoz heat travels not as a particles which repel (or i should say interact with each other) but as a vibration

Comment: Heat flow is much like electrical current flow, it is proportional to the temperature gradient, the heat conductivity, and the cross-sectional area and it does depend on particle interaction

Comment: so according to you if we take a long conductor and heat its ends at the same temperature then the temperature of the rod would not change just as if we took a rod and connected both the ends with the positive or negative ends of two batteries then the current would not flow through the rod. Does it really happen like that? If possible PLz share some source from which I can learn about it

Comment: Be aware of the difference between transient and steady state conditions.  If both ends were heated, heat would flow into the rod until the temperature was stable throughout.